# React Native PIP

Tags: ios, react-native, webrtc, video-streaming, picture-in-picture

I need to add Picture in Picture mode to a react native app (iOS) and I'm not sure how to go about it. I see that it is a feature of react-native-video but I'm using a different module for the video so I can only add PiP as a separate feature.

Any doc/blog with some details on how to set that up would help. Thanks!

Comment: @famfamfam I wasn't able to solve this no. We changed our use case to have the PiP mode within the app. That was possible with  [react-native-root-siblings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-root-siblings) & [react-native-draggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable)