# How to implement PIP (Picture in Picture) Mode in React Native?

Tags: java, android, react-native, npm, picture-in-picture

I need to implement PIP mode using react native, but it should update date every second while user enters in PIP mode.

I tried using following packages but not worked:
[react-native-pip-android](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pip-android)
[react-native-picture-in-picture](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-picture-in-picture)

Comment: what are the error you are getting in above libraries. (do you want to implement in android only?)
check this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/69613230/9608873

Comment: @Ragnar I tried above liabraries, but unable to update data in View while user is in PIP Mode

Comment: please share the code. create a snack if it's possible

Comment: Nothing in code, just a simple View with Text which updates every second

Answer (score 1):

I might have found a solution. The problem is when an Android app enters PIP, the onPause function is called. This is specified here https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/picture-in-picture#continuing_playback where google recommends continuing video playback in the onPause function. This is okay for Android because native views don't care about the current Activity states and can be updated even though the app is paused, or entered background state. However RN's UI update, and very importantly anything not using HeadlessJS (https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android) will just run unreliably, if they are actually running at all. The result is none of your states will update without headlessJS mode, and your UI will be a static image because it won't update. So the trick that seems to work for me is 2 folds: 1. however updating your data should be done via a headlessJs Task; and 2. trigger RN UI rendering via a method.

For #1, I just can't get the seemingly abandoned libraries (react-native-pip-android) to work. The concept is correct though and you should implement PIP just like that package. I first wanted an event emitter that notifies RN that my app entered PIP mode. It's a simple `getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext().getJSModule(RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class).emit("YourEventIDHere", boolean)` in the `MainActivity`'s `onPictureInPictureModeChange`. However a regular event listener inside a component's useEffect won't work; I spent a day to deduce that event needs to be registered via `AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask` that could be due to once `onPictureInPictureModeChange` is called, app is in background and non headlessTask will not execute. Then I nested this listener to a vanilla zustand store then chained that store into a useStore hook.

For #2 none of the libraries will help you because this is RN's limitation. I was going to wrap RN's rerender UI function inside a RN module method, then call it from my hook; however I could not understand how RN worked and found a more straightforward but sketchy solution - I invoke `onResume` immediately after PIP triggering `super.onPause` to resume RN to the foreground. I need to flush out my other logics first to test in release, but my UI is fully responsive in PIP under debug.

```
  public void onPause() {
    // If called while in PiP mode, do not pause playback
    super.onPause();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
      if (isInPictureInPictureMode()) {
        this.onResume(); // <--- this 
        // Continue playback
      } else {
        // Use existing playback logic for paused Activity behavior.
      }
    } else {

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing `react-native-pip-android` and remove any changes made in `android/MainActivity` before.

Add this snippet in `MainActivity.java` to be able to listen to the changes:

```
import com.reactnativepipandroid.PipAndroidModule;
import android.content.res.Configuration;

@Override
public void onPictureInPictureModeChanged (boolean isInPictureInPictureMode, Configuration newConfig) {
    PipAndroidModule.pipModeChanged(isInPictureInPictureMode);
}
```

Build the project after the above change.

***Note:*** Inside `build.gradle` you need to set the minimum sdk version to **24**. PIP in android is supported from **API level 24**.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
         minSdkVersion = 24
    }
}
```

**React Native Implementation**

```
import PipHandler, { usePipModeListener } from 'react-native-pip-android';

export default function App() {
  // Use this boolean to show / hide ui when pip mode changes
  const inPipMode = usePipModeListener();

  if (inPipMode) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>PIP Mode</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>
        These text components will be hidden in pip mode
      </Text>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => PipHandler.enterPipMode(300, 214)}
        style={styles.box}>
        <Text>Click to Enter Pip Mode</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is there a way the implement the same in ios?

Comment: As of now there is no support for iOS, I am also trying to figure out.
I will update you if I get any thing.